# can't connect to MySQL on raspian

Tags: mysql, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I installed **MySQL** with `sudo apt install mariadb-server` on a **Raspberry pi 4** with **raspian** installed but it raises `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'` (or `'pi'@'localhost'` if I don't use `sudo`)

[image: error]

Comment: And what's your question about this? What makes you think that `sudo` is neccessary here?

Comment: the question is "what should I do to connect", as you can see I tried with both sudo and none